# Which board is better overall for .net mf development, the Tahoe 2 or the GHI EMX module?

Tags: .net-micro-framework, arm7

Which board is better overall for .net mf development, the Tahoe 2 or the GHI EMX module?

1. [Tahoe 2](http://devicesolutions.net/Products/TahoeII.aspx)
2. [GHI EMX](http://www.ghielectronics.com/product/129)

I'm looking at a general purpose board for plugging in different types of sensors (at once) and using functions like the NIC and SD file io.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the boards? I am sure each board has its own application where it thrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GHI EMX seems to have a bigger number of peripherals and IO ports. If you're looking for using lots of sensor at the same time its the better choice.

Although I like the built in accelerometer in Tahoe 2.

Comment: thankyou I like your answer straight forward and to the point.